# ContentTemplate and Multiple View Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I have a window that displays a custom `user control`, a `content control`, and a `textbox`... When the user picks a `radio button` on the custom `user control`, a dependency property changes which in turn changes the view to be from a data template

The problem I'm having: I cannot properly retrieve the underlying dependency properties that are exposed on the swapped `user control`. For instance, each user control exposes an `IsSearching` dependency property.

Based on the value, I want to disable some functionality until the `IsSearching` is complete. I've tried setting the `textbox` text a couple of ways but can't find it the proper way to retrieve the binding.

I also tried binding the dependency property to a property on the mainviewmodel (CTALightViewModel) but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  Definitely a little lost on this so any help is appreciated.

```
<views:CTAAddress x:Name="CTAAddressView" IsSearching="{Binding VMBusy, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**DataTemplates**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddressTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:CTAAddressViewModel}">
        <views:CTAAddress />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PremiseTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:CTAPremiseViewModel}">
        <views:CTAPremise  />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:CTALightViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

**Content Control**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ViewSwap" Content="{Binding }">
    <ContentControl.Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SearchOptions, Path=IsSelected}" Value="0">
                   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AddressTemplate}" />
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SearchOptions, Path=IsSelected}" Value="1">
                  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PremiseTemplate}" />
              </DataTrigger>                  
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

**TextBox To Display**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ViewSwap, Path=?????, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I needed to implement a view model base to achieve this.  I have created one and had the other view models inherit from this base.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding to `CTALightViewModel`, do you have a property in `CTALightViewModel` called `IsSearching` that you can set as the path in your binding? e.g

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ViewSwap, Path=?????, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

If not, you could create the property called `IsSearching` in your `CTALightViewModel`, and in the property's setter, you would call your `OnPropertyChanged()` so that the UI learns about the change whenever it occurs.

Comment: I do have a property called `VMBusy` which implements the `OnPropertyChanged()` in `CTALightViewModel`.  I am just unsure which section to place the binding.  For instance, do I put it in bound to each `data template` and the corresponding dependency property or do I try to grab it from the `content control` element itself.  I have tried both ways but neither have worked.